# sql date time on sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a modified field column on a table.
When I run a job at 2:45pm want to get data that got modified after 3:30am first

and when i run the same job @3:30 am want to get data that got modified after 2:45pm yesterday

How to write the sql for this on sql server?

Employee Table
Name
Age
Street
City
State
Zipcode
Creation_Date
Created_By
Modified_Date
Modified_By

Today if I ran this sql @3:30 am want to get data that got Modified_Date  after yesterday 2:45 pm

Today if I ran this sql @2:45 pm want to get data that got Modified_Date  after 3:30 am

Hope I am clear what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and maybe table structure to your question?

Comment: Are you sure you should be building this yourself? There are various features built into SQL Server (Change Tracking, Change Data Capture) etc that are built to do this sort of thing; and tend to have better granularity so that e.g. you know which rows you have/have not seen - with your current proposal, if you're running at 3:30am, you may see some rows that have already been inserted at 3:30am, but there may be other rows yet to be inserted which will also be timestamped 3:30am. A minute (or even a second) is an *awfully long time* for a computer.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `DATEADD` with a negative value.

```
select
*
from YourTable
where YourDateTimeColumn >= dateadd(minute,-1395,getdate())
```

If you want to use a variable to ensure 0300

```
declare @date datetime = (select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar) + ' 03:30:00')

select @date

    select
    *
    from YourTable
    where YourDateTimeColumn >= dateadd(minute,-1395,@date)
```

Comment: This assumes the job runs when it is supposed to and isn't delayed in any way

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table
where Modified > case when cast(getdate() as time) < '14:45:00'
                      then dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate())-1,0) + cast('14:45:00' as datetime)
                      else dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0) + cast('03:30:00' as datetime)
                      end
```

Comment: this is not working. any changes to do? getting error as "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Comment: Was missing a parenthesis.  Try now

Comment: Thanks, for quick response but still getting error as "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS' ----- using sql server 2008

Comment: sorry, please ignore above now getting error as "Operand data type date is invalid for add operator"

Comment: Apologies, try now.

Comment: thanks, that worked even this worked CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) + CAST('14:45:00' AS DATETIME)

Comment: Glad it worked!  If it is the correct solution for your problem, for the benefit of other Stack Overflow users with the same issue, please mark it as the answer.